# host not pinging guest VM

Tags: centos, networking, nat, vmware-workstation

on a Win10 host i have a CentOS7 guest VM running on VMWARE Worstation14. To meet my requirement, i have configured two v-adapters.

1. ens33 - NAT -- dhcp'ed IP to have internet access for the VM (192.168.33.128)
2. ens37 - HOST ONLY -- static IP to have communication with other guest vm in the internal network and app development(192.168.242.128)

I checked the ips created on the host and i see two vmnets being created, (vmnet1)192.168.33.1 and (vmnet2)192.168.220.1 along with the 3rd eth adapter for the host itself, 192.168.0.x which it receives as a dhcp client.

I am new to vmware and its network config part. So i am filled with following queries.

I did some ping tests to determine which of the vmnets is for NAT and which is for host only. I found vmnet1 is for NAT and vmnet2 is for host only. But i wonder why vmnet2 is in the series of 192.168.220.x when the guest vm has 192.128.242.x?

Also i checked the gateway (route -n) and found the gateway is 192.168.33.2. Seeing the IP series i believe it to be the gateway for the NAT adapter but then where is the gateway for the host only adapter?

```
bash-4.1$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.33.2     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 ens33
192.168.33.0      0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens33
192.168.242.0     0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens37
```

Also I try pinging the guest vm ens37 from host and find Request timed out.

```
ping 192.168.242.128

Request timed out
```

however the guest vm ens33 is pingable and is giving me access to the VM. I expect that. Why is the guest VM not reachable to host via ens37? 
All these doubts are filling up my mind...

Comment: Are IP addresses configured over NAT static in nature on the guest VMs? Even though my host gets dhcp IP, I donot see the NAT IP of my guest VM changing after multiple reboots?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a UNIX or Linux issue.

Answer (score 2):

So sometimes the answer is quite simple if you look at it the other way. the mistake I had done is that I created the host only network adapter for the guest VMs but the static IP I was simply not correct. Duh! what was I thinking. It was only when I did tracert , I saw the trace going out of my system to my router and the outside world!! that spooked me. It should have been declined somewhere in the virtual bridge of my system itself. Then enlightenment occurred to me and I realised, that I was being dumb. I reset the static IPs of the guest VMs to 192.168.220.x and its all working now.